# Angular 2 over write table row instead of appending ! Currently using *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

Actually i'm trying to represent each service object as a table row, but when i call my javascript function again *ngFor creates appends another set of rows to the existing rows.

```
<tr class="table table-hover  table-responsive "  *ngFor="let service of services">
          <td>{{ service.serviceName }}</td>
          <td>{{ service.state }}</td>

          <td>{{ service.domainName }}</td>
          <td>{{ service.releaseVersion }}</td>
          <td>{{ service.editionDisplayName }}</td>
          <td>{{ service.creationDate }}</td>
```

// the table row gets appended instead of overwriting!

JQuery object parsing!

```
onCreateServer(){
this.serverCreationStatus = 'Server Instance Created! ' + this.serverName;
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/PodChecker/', {params:
    {Podurl: this.serverName
    }}).subscribe( (response: Response) => {
        console.log(response);
      const data = response.json();
        console.log(data);
        this.Service_Instances = data;
        this.dict = data;
        console.log('Data[services]' + JSON.stringify(data['services']));
        console.log(this.dict);
        this.Service_Instances = this.dict['services'];
        //this.setValues(this.dict['services']);
        console.log('Must Check' + JSON.stringify(this.setValues(this.dict['services'])));
        console.log('This Services Output:' + JSON.stringify(this.services ));

      },
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

Set Values function

```
setValues(array){

const jsonVal = array;
console.log('This is a surprise!!' + JSON.stringify(jsonVal.keys));


   jQuery.each( array, ( key, value ) => {
    console.log('Jquery Output 1st' + key + ': ' + value.state );
    console.log('Jquery Output 1st' + key + ': ' + value.serviceName );
    console.log('Jquery Output 1st' + key + ': ' + value.domainName );
    console.log('Jquery Output 1st' + key + ': ' + value.releaseVersion );
    console.log('Jquery Output 1st' + key + ': ' + value.creationDate );
    console.log('Jquery Output 1st' + key + ': ' + value.BI_SERVICE_URL );
    console.log('Jquery Output 1st' + key + ': ' + value.editionDisplayName );
     console.log('GEtting Essbase values' + JSON.stringify(value.components.BI.attributes.profile_essbase.value));
     this.services.push(new ServerProperties(JSON.stringify(value.serviceName), JSON.stringify(value.state),
       JSON.stringify(value.domainName), JSON.stringify(value.releaseVersion),
JSON.stringify(value.editionDisplayName),
});
}
```

calling the function!

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="serverName"
>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-left"  (click)="onCreateServer()">Get Details</button>
```

Comment: How you are populating `services`? and are you updating it?

Comment: I'm hitting rest url and getting response, I'm putting the response JS object.

Comment: empty `services array`, before writing new data to it in rest url response.

Comment: @Satpal Any solutions from your end?

Comment: @anoop If I even empty the js object the previous data won't be overwritten!

Comment: @anoop Here the problem is data is getting appended! If it generates a table it will append to the previously generate table!

Comment: @RaghavendraSS : where you set data of `services`,? if it is  `this.setValues()`, then post its code too.

Comment: Can you rephrase what you want to say? The title says ".. overwrite table row instead of appending.." and in one of your comments you said "Here the problem is data is getting appended!"

Comment: @brijmcq Actually from the above code i'm getting services object and suppose there are 4 objects there will be 4 rows in my table, if i click get details again, the new data with 4 or 3 objects will be appended to the already displayed data! so on 2nd click there are 7-8 rows, it's not getting overwritten but appended. Table rows are appending instead of overwriting.

Comment: @RaghavendraSS have you tried making it null every time you call the onCreateServer()?

Comment: @brijmcq I did  this.services = [];, onCreateServer() method after calling setValues, However it quickly updates and the data won't even show. So i can't empty services inside onCreateServer().

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your `this.services = []` everytime you call the onCreateServer() like this

```
onCreateServer(){
this.serverCreationStatus = 'Server Instance Created! ' + this.serverName;
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/PodChecker/', {params:
    {Podurl: this.serverName
    }}).subscribe( (response: Response) => {
      this.services= [];
//... more code
```

And not after you call the setValues.

Hope this helps.